# Android list view shows blank elements

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, r.java-file

In my App i download a list of strings from the web

then i'm using AsyncTask to update the listview on my activity.
at prePostExecute im creating the array adapter(private member)

at doInBackground i download the list and return it

at onPostExecute i set the returned list to the adapter and then connects the listview and the adapter

in my activity i see just 1 blank element(instead of 2 elements) , when i click it i can see the Text but when im not its blank.

also , when my adapter is not android.R.layout.simple_list_1 but android.R.layout.acitiviy_list_item (and 2 other templates) i can see 2 elements with visible text but the text is small and gray

**code:
XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#4CB8FB"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Search"
            android:textColor="#FAFAFA"
            android:textSize="40sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_btn_search" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:scrollingCache="true" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**code Behind**

```
public class ProductPickerActivity extends Activity {
    private ListView listView;
    private EditText inputSearch;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private final Integer PRODUCT_REQUEST_ID = 5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_listview);

        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchInput);

        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                ProductPickerActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            }
        });
        new InitializeUi().execute(this);
        setupUI(findViewById(R.id.parent));
    }

    private class InitializeUi extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, List<IProduct>> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // Get ListView object from xml
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

            // Define a new Adapter
            // First parameter - Context
            // Second parameter - Layout for the row
            // Third parameter - ID of the TextView to which the data is written
            // Forth - the Array of data

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.activity_list_item, new ArrayList<String>());

            // ListView Item Click Listener
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    // ListView Clicked item index
                    int itemPosition = position;

                    // ListView Clicked item value
                    String itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProductViewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("ProductName", itemValue);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PRODUCT_REQUEST_ID);
                }

            });
        }

        @Override
        protected List<IProduct> doInBackground(Object... params) {
            // Defined Array values to show in ListView
            IProductManager manager = new ProductManager(getApplicationContext());
            // download from web
            List<IProduct> lst = manager.GetProductList();
            return lst;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<IProduct> lst) {

            String[] values = new String[lst.size()];
            Integer i = 0;

            for (IProduct p : lst) {
                values[i] = p.getName();
                i = i + 1;
                Log.d("ProductPickerActivity", "Got Values : " + p.getName());

                adapter.add(p.getName());

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            // Assign adapter to ListView
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            ((BaseAdapter) listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

            listView.refreshDrawableState();

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

apply the edit code below to `onPostExecute` hope its work

```
 // Assign adapter to ListView
 listView.setAdapter(adapter);

//then add values to adatper
  String [] values = new String[lst.size()];
   int i =0; //<<-- change to int
           for(IProduct p : lst)
             {
                values[i] = p.getName();
                i++;//<-- add +1
                Log.d("ProductPickerActivity","Got Values : "+p.getName());
                adapter.add(p.getName());
             }
//finaly notify adapter data changed
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```